# Getting error for users "AADSTS90093: Does not have access to consent." after admin has granted consent

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Using Azure Active Directory in a multi-tenant environment.

Admin has given consent to the application for all users to log on.

Users have been restricted from consenting.

After admin has given consent users are still not able to log on and receive the "AADSTS90093: Does not have access to consent." error.

Answer (score 1):

The way in which you did admin consent was probably erroneous or you were not signed into an admin account. Try out one of these two ways:

1. Inside the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com), login to an admin account, go to the **App Registration** blade, select your app, and hit the **Grant Permissions** button.
2. Construct a new auth request and append on `&prompt=admin_consent`.

This error is caused when your app is requesting an [admin-restricted scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications).  These are scopes that require an admin to consent on behalf of their users.

Comment: This app requires only user.read and does not require any admin-restricted scopes. Other tenant's users are able to access the site. It is only where the admin of the tenant has restricted the ability of individual users to consent that we are seeing this issue.

Comment: Make sure you do proper **admin_consent** using one of the steps in the answer.  Just signing into the app normally as an admin and consenting simply consents for that user.

Comment: This app is registered in apps 2.0. I don't think &prompt=admin_consent works for it. Nor does this information show in the blade.